# android threads

Tags: android

I'm searching for some good material on android threads but I couldn't find references for a complete description about this subject. So if you know any valuable reference please point them to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few resources to start with, directly from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com):

- [Reference: **java.lang.Thread**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Article: **Painless Threading**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)
- [Common Task: **Handling Expensive Operations on the UI Thread**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Application Fundamentals: **Processes and Threads**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#procthread)